# Service Broker enabled on tempdb in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, service-broker

I am seeking an answer what might me the reason/scenario to have Service Broker enabled on tempdb. I have a legacy SQL Server and it is enabled there. Is it safe to disable it? Is it possible to display it's dependencies? Is it possible to check when was it enabled?

I admit that I do not have much knowledge about queueing messages and I have never implemented a solution that was using Service Broker.